# GLMER and AIC: convergence problems

Tags: lme4-nlme, convergence, aic

I am trying to find the "best" model for a binomial GLMER using AIC in R. Here is the equation:

Survival~Age+Group+Age:Group+Age^2+Age^3+(1|Year)+(1|Individual)

Where Year and Individual represent temporal differences and repeated measures, respectively. I am trying to determine if Age:Group, Age^2, and/or Age^3 are good predictors. However, I am running into convergence problems with some models when I calculate AIC values using the MuMIn package. The models that have convergence problems are caused by one or the other or both random effects. Thus, is it appropriate to use GLMERs at all to estimate the "best" model?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it that MuMIn doesn't calculate the AICs or that the models do not converge in the first place? If the latter, it's possible you have too few observations for testing higher-order age terms, or that either year- or individual-related variance is low enough to cause non-convergence. Can you post an output of one of the problematic models?